# Python + getopt - Problems with parsing

Tags: python, parsing, gerrit

I have some problems with writing some Gerrit http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/ hooks.

http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.2.0/config-hooks.html

If I parse the command line for
patchset-created --change  --change-url  --project  --branch  --uploader  --commit  --patchset

```
def main():

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    showUsage()
    exit()

if (sys.argv[1] == 'update-projects'):
    updateProjects()
    exit()

need = ['action=', 'change=', 'change-url=', 'commit=', 'project=', 'branch=', 'uploader=',
        'patchset=', 'abandoner=', 'reason=', 'submitter=', 'comment=', 'CRVW=', 'VRIF=' , 'patchset=' , 'restorer=', 'author=']
print  sys.argv[1:]
print '-----' 
optlist, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', need)
id = url = hash = who = comment = reason =  codeReview = verified = restorer = ''
print optlist

for o, a in optlist:
    if o == '--change': id = a
    elif o == '--change-url': url = a
    elif o == '--commit': hash = a
    elif o == '--action': what = a
    elif o == '--uploader': who = a
    elif o == '--submitter': who = a
    elif o == '--abandoner': who = a
    elif o == '--author' : who = a
    elif o == '--branch': branch = a
    elif o == '--comment': comment = a
    elif o == '--CRVW' : codeReview = a
    elif o == '--VRIF' : verified = a
    elif o == '--patchset' : patchset = a
    elif o == '--restorer' : who = a
    elif o == '--reason' : reason = a
```

Command line input:

```
--change I87f7802d438d5640779daa9ac8196aeb3eec8c2a
--change-url http://<hostname>:8080/308
--project private/bar
--branch master
--uploader xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)
--commit 49aae9befaf27a5fede51b498f0660199f47b899 --patchset 1
```

print  sys.argv[1:]

```
['--action', 'new',
'--change','I87f7802d438d5640779daa9ac8196aeb3eec8c2a',
'--change-url',
'http://<hostname>:8080/308',
'--project', 'private/bar',
'--branch', 'master',
'--uploader', 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', '(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)',
'--commit', '49aae9befaf27a5fede51b498f0660199f47b899',
'--patchset', '1']
```

print optlist

```
[('--action', 'new'),
('--change', 'I87f7802d438d5640779daa9ac8196aeb3eec8c2a'),
('--change-url', 'http://<hostname>:8080/308'),
('--project', 'private/bar'),
('--branch', 'master'),
('--uploader', 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx')]
```

I don't know why the script generates

```
'--uploader', 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', '(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)'
and not
'--uploader', 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)'
```

because so the script dont't parse --commit  --patchset  ...

When I parse comment-added all things works:

Command line input:

```
   -change I87f7802d438d5640779daa9ac8196aeb3eec8c2a
   --change-url http://<hostname>.intra:8080/308
   --project private/bar
   --branch master
   --author xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)
   --commit 49aae9befaf27a5fede51b498f0660199f47b899
   --comment asdf
   --CRVW 0 
   --VRIF 0
```

print sys.argv[1:]

```
  '--action', 'comment',
    '--change', 'I87f7802d438d5640779daa9ac8196aeb3eec8c2a',
    '--change-url',
    'http://<hostname>:8080/308',
    '--project', 'private/bar',
    '--branch', 'master',
    '--author', 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)', <<< That's right!
    '--commit', '49aae9befaf27a5fede51b498f0660199f47b899',
    '--comment', 'asdf',
    '--CRVW', '0',
    '--VRIF', '0']
```

Answer (score 2):

As the options names and values are space-separated, you have to put the values in quotes if they contain spaces themselves.

If you write `--uploader xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)`, the last two strings will actually end up in `args` from the line

```
optlist, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', need)
```

as they are not associated with `--uploader`

Answer (score 1):

You should quote an argument, if it contains spaces, like for all commandline tools:

```
--uploader "xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxx-xxxx.xx)"
```

Comment: I get this stream from Gerrit but why work this when Gerrit use comment-added... That's the problem what I don't understand

Comment: Why don't you just do `' '.join(a)` with arguments for `--uploader`? I suppose Gerrit does the same. It's not that difficult.

Comment: Now I shift the arguments before the script starts and this workaround work.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using gnu_getopt() as it would allow you to mix option and non-option arguments.
From the [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html)

> The getopt() function stops processing options as soon as a non-option argument is encountered

If you use gnu_getopt, the rest of the options namely commit and pathset will still be parsed correctly even though the uploader argument has missing quotes

Comment: Thx. This is a good hint but this is not an option I need alle arguments.